# Cant seem to flatten numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array which when `print`-ed looks like this:

```
print(a.shape)
(21,)
print(a)
[array([8.55570588e+03, 4.23078573e+05, 2.81254715e+07, 2.10356201e+09,
       4.24558286e+05, 2.10032147e+07, 1.39638949e+09, 1.04453957e+11,
       2.81593475e+07, 1.39354786e+09, 9.26480296e+10, 6.92992796e+12,
       2.10047682e+09, 1.03982525e+11, 6.91296507e+12, 5.17021191e+14])
 array([8.55404706e+03, 4.23328400e+05, 2.80891690e+07, 2.09651453e+09,
       4.23874124e+05, 2.09628073e+07, 1.39044370e+09, 1.03745119e+11,
       2.81060928e+07, 1.38935279e+09, 9.21288996e+10, 6.87207671e+12,
       2.09626303e+09, 1.03584989e+11, 6.86712650e+12, 5.12107449e+14])
 array([6.71569608e+03, 3.32364057e+05, 2.20526342e+07, 1.64564735e+09,
       3.32826578e+05, 1.64539763e+07, 1.09116635e+09, 8.13888141e+10,
       2.20612069e+07, 1.08976996e+09, 7.22409501e+10, 5.38629510e+12,
       1.64474898e+09, 8.11907944e+10, 5.38026989e+12, 4.01021156e+14])
 array([  97,  120,  147,  106,  115,  151,  300,  268,  326,  454,  684,
       1594, 2202, 2229, 1205,    2])
 array([   1,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1,    0,    1,    0,    2,    1,
         11,  359, 1355, 3921, 4348])
 array([   1,    0,    0,    1,    0,    0,    6,   11,   31,  644, 2312,
       3046, 3618,  321,    7,    2])
 625.0 625.0 625.0 537178.875 1874648.75 1373895.875 1.275734191674592
 2.066594119913508 1.6749058704798478 0.11276410212887233 2.55304393588347
 1.1167704949278905 2.177796835501801 1.1323869527951895
 1.3940068452456151]
```

Ideally I would want all of these values in one big array of length (3*16 + 3*16 + 15)

`np.concatenate` did not work, `flatten` also did bring the desired result.

Comment: Can you try `np.hstack(a)`?

Comment: Why did you end up with this kind of structure? Wouldn't it be better to build the desired array structure in the code before? And what is an array of size `3*16 + 3*16 + 3 * 5)`?

Comment: Judging by the shape of `a`, the issue is coming from the fact that the sub arrays of `a` are not of equal length. I don’t necessarily know what you should do about it, but I’m pretty sure that’s the problem.

Comment: @MrT `3*16 + 3*16 + 15` corresponds to the way the numbers are represented in the array 6 arrays à 16 elements plus  15 items

Comment: @titipata `np.hstack(a)` did end up working, if you post as an answer I'll accept

Comment: You array is *already* flat, this is what `a.shape == (21,)` is telling you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way is to use `np.hstack` in order to flatten list of array and float. Example usage is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
a = [np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([4, 5, 6]), 7, 8, 9]
np.hstack(a)

>> array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```